# Change the item background color of a combobox in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to change the background color of an item of a combobox when I use the method AddString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derive a class from CComboBox and override OnCtlColor. In OnCtlColor when the nCtlColor parameter is CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX, call the DC::SetBkColor method.

Maybe something like this:

```
HBRUSH CMyComboBox::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX)
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));

    return CComboBox::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}
```

*Inspiration taken from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117778) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/45d6426c-eac4-45c8-b5b0-d85005c72c23).*

Comment: Does this works with CComboBoxEx too ? Because I've tried and it doesn't seems to work...